# "Element click intercepted" Error while trying to click on CheckBox

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox

I want to click on a check box after I load up a page, but I get the error message below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <img class="checkboximage" src="/images/nav/ns_x.gif" alt=""> is not clickable at point (843, 7). Other element would receive the click: <a class="ns-help" onclick="nlPopupHelp('EDIT_TRAN_CUSTINVC');" tabindex="0" onkeypress="(event.keyCode == 13 || event.charCode == 32) &amp;&amp; nlPopupHelp('EDIT_TRAN_CUSTINVC');">...</a>
```

This is what I have right now: I've tried several other methods before this

```
collectionsbox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#custbody_in_collections_fs_inp")
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", collectionsbox)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='custbody_in_collections_fs']//img[@class='checkboximage']"))).click()

collectionsbox.click() #USUALLY FAILS RIGHT HERE

savebutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='btn_multibutton_submitter']")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='btn_multibutton_submitter']"))).click()

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", savebutton)
savebutton.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

I've tried the EC method, waited several seconds, scroll down to view the element. I've even used Xpath, ID, and CSS.

```
<input onclick="setEventCancelBubble(event); this.isvalid=(nlapiValidateField(null,'custbody_in_collections')); if (this.isvalid) {setWindowChanged(window, true);nlapiFieldChanged(null,'custbody_in_collections');;} else if ( window.loadcomplete &amp;&amp; !document.page_is_resetting ) {setFormValue(this, !this.checked);}" aria-labelledby="custbody_in_collections_fs_lbl" onchange="NLCheckboxOnChange(this); " onkeypress="NLCheckboxOnKeyPress(event);  return true;" name="custbody_in_collections" id="custbody_in_collections_fs_inp" type="checkbox" value="T" class="checkbox" style="">
<input type="hidden" name="custbody_in_collections_send" style="">
<img class="checkboximage" src="/images/nav/ns_x.gif" alt="" style="">
```

All I need is click the checkbox and click save up top.

Comment: notice the "CancelBubble" code there?  This page is relying on all other clicks to bubble up/down to the overlayed span... which creates a pop-up.  Seems like you want to click the checkbox anyway, not the image.  The only reason Selenium finds the image to be clickable is that span's onClick eventhandler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like another element on the DOM is unintentionally hiding the element you are trying to click. You can try executing Javascript for the click instead. This usually resolves the issue for me.

Instead of `collectionsbox.click() #USUALLY FAILS RIGHT HERE`, you can replace with:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", collectionsbox)
```

Answer (score 2):

To address element is not clickable at point (x, y) error. We can follow below approaches to resolve this issue

**Solution**

**1. Action Class**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("yourelement ID"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

**2. Element not getting clicked as it is not within Viewport**

use JavascriptExecutor to get element within the Viewport:

```
checkBox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"yourelement Xpath")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(checkBox).click(checkBox).perform()
```